# Add reward video to Xamarin android app IsLoaded always return false

Tags: xamarin.android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I'm trying to add a reward AdMob video to my app my code in onCreate is

```
Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "APP_CODE" );
mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.GetRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.RewardedVideoAdListener = this;
mRewardedVideoAd.LoadAd(@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                    new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
```

when i try to show the video by the following code

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded)
                mRewardedVideoAd.Show();
```

the mRewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded always return false

Is There any solution for this?